# How to get The Max Rownumbered Value As The Joining Key brings Identical Records

Tags: t-sql

I am joining around ten tables to my base table using an ID field.

There is a unique field more like a rownumber. This field is `bigint` and uniquely identifies each record in each table, but I can not join using this field as it exists only in each individual table.

How could I efficiently use this unique field for each table to bring only the maximum so that I could use the maximum whenever I have identical records?

Comment: I do not follow "How could I efficiently use this unique field for each table to bring only the maximum so that I could use the maximum whenever I have identical records?" It would help to see sample data and an expected outcome. Preferably, throw something up on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Please add more details in your question. Provide the metadata of few tables at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have enough information to work with, but it sounds like you may need to perform an aggregate in a derived table (per joined table) and then join to it.

Code:

```
    SELECT bt.ID, unique_field
      FROM [basetable] bt
INNER JOIN  (SELECT MAX(unique_field) as unique_field, ID
               FROM [othertable]
           GROUP BY ID) MaxOther
ON bt.ID = MaxOther.ID
```

Results:

```
ID  UNIQUE_FIELD
1   1
2   3
3   6
```

Here is a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deb29/4) with the answer in it.